# Выбор элементов от и до jQuery

Tags: jquery

В общем, есть `div` с произвольным количеством дочерних `div`-ов.
Нужно реализовать выбор/мультивыбор дочерних `div` (на подобии выбора файлов в проводнике).

Если зажата клавиша <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, то добавляем `div` к выбранным. 
Если клавиша не зажата, то снимаем выбор у всех и добавляем к текущему. 
Если зажата клавиша <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, то нужно выбрать n элементов, от и до.

Код:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      // отслеживание зажатий ctrl и shift
      var ctrl = false;
      var shift = false;
      $(window).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 17) {
          ctrl = true;
          $('.key').text('Зажат "CTRL"');
        } else if (e.keyCode == 16) {
          shift = true;
          $('.key').text('Зажат "SHIFT"');
        }
      });
      $(window).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 17) {
          ctrl = false;
        } else if (e.keyCode == 16) {
          shift = false;
        }
        $('.key').text('');
      });

      // выбор элементов
      $('.images').on('click', 'div', function() {

        // ctrl зажат - добавим к текущему элементу класс "active"
        if (ctrl) {
          $(this).toggleClass('active');
        }

        // Shift зажат
        else if (shift) {
          // нужно выбрать элементы от и до ( тут нужна помощь )
        }

        // ctrl и shift НЕзажаты - снимим у всех эл. класс "active" и добавим к текущему эл. класс "active"
        else {
          $('.images > div').removeClass('active');
          $(this).toggleClass('active');
        }
      });
    });
```

В [**этом**](http://jsfiddle.net/qv2UL/379/) примере я все реализовал, кроме выбора при зажатой клавише <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>. Дальше застрял...

Comment: А выделение через shift должно происходить от последнего выбранного элемента или от "краев"?

Comment: Выделение от первого выбранного до текущего Выделение должно происходить и с верху в низ и с низу вверх. И если на пути выделения уже есть выбранные элементы то они тоже должны попадать в выборку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Элементы выделяются и сверху и снизу, а если нет выделеных, то с первого элемента:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // отслеживание зажатий ctrl и shift
  var ctrl = false;
  var shift = false;
  $(window).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 17) {
      ctrl = true;
      $('.key').text('Зажат "CTRL"');
    } else if (e.keyCode == 16) {
      shift = true;
      $('.key').text('Зажат "SHIFT"');
    }
  });
  $(window).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 17) {
      ctrl = false;
    } else if (e.keyCode == 16) {
      shift = false;
    }
    $('.key').text('');
  });

  // выбор элементов
  $('.images').on('click', 'div', function() {

    // ctrl зажат - добавим к текущему элементу класс "active"
    if (ctrl) {
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
    }

    // Shift зажат
    else if (shift) {

      let images = $('.images');
      let fromElement = images.children().index($('.active'));

      let currentElement = images.children().index($(this)) + 1;
      fromElement = fromElement == -1 ? 0 : fromElement;

      if (fromElement < currentElement) {
       $('.active').removeClass('active');
        images.children().each(
          function(index, element) {
            if (index >= fromElement && index < currentElement) {
              if (!$(element).hasClass('active'))
                $(element).toggleClass('active');
            }
          });

      } else {
        images.children().each(
          function(index, element) {
            if (index <= fromElement && index > currentElement - 2) {
              if (!$(element).hasClass('active'))
                $(element).toggleClass('active');
            }
          });
      }
    }

    // ctrl и shift НЕзажаты - снимим у всех эл. класс "active" и добавим к текущему эл. класс "active"
    else {
      $('.images > div').removeClass('active');
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.images {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.images div {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="images">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="key">
  <div>
```

Comment: Проводник (на что ориентируются в вопросе) все же рабоатет не совсем так

Answer (score 1):

Выделение происходит как сверху вниз, так и снизу вверх. Основываясь на работу проводника, с зажатым <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> можно убирать выделение у уже выбранных элементах.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // отслеживание зажатий ctrl и shift
  var ctrl = false;
  var shift = false;
  var last = 0;
  var current = 0;
  $(window).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 17) {
      ctrl = true;
      $('.key').text('Зажат "CTRL"');
    } else if (e.keyCode == 16) {
      shift = true;
      $('.key').text('Зажат "SHIFT"');
    }
  });
  $(window).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 17) {
      ctrl = false;
    } else if (e.keyCode == 16) {
      shift = false;
    }
    $('.key').text('');
  });




  // выбор элементов
  $('.images').on('click', 'div', function() {

    // ctrl зажат - добавим к текущему элементу класс "active"
    if (ctrl) {
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      last = $(this).index() + 1;
    }

    // Shift зажат
    else if (shift) {
      $('.images > div').removeClass('active');
      current = $(this).index() + 1;
      // нужно выбрать элементы от и до ( тут нужна помощь )
      if (current > last) {
        for (var i = last; i <= current; i++) {
          $('.images > div:nth-child(' + i + ')').addClass('active');
        }
      } else {
        for (var i = last; i >= current; i--) {
          $('.images > div:nth-child(' + i + ')').addClass('active');
        }
      }

    }

    // ctrl и shift НЕзажаты - снимим у всех эл. класс "active" и добавим к текущему эл. класс "active"
    else {
      $('.images > div').removeClass('active');
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      last = $(this).index() + 1;
    }

  });

});
```

```css
.images {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.images div {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="images">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="key"></div>
```